# eval() function in R

Tags: r, eval

I am trying to use `eval()` function in R to calculate expressions.
I am retrieving the the formula from a data frame and storing it in a variable say 'form'.
Now I tried to evaluate this expression as follows:

```
df 
x y z
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

form = "x+y+z"
expr = expression(form)
df = data.table::data.table(df)
result = eval(expr, df[1])
```

I am getting the result as "x+y+z" instead of 6.
If I directly pass the formula in to the `expr = expression(..)`, I get the correct result, but I couldn't do that coz I am retrieving the formula from other data frame. Please suggest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`expression` doesn’t do what you think it does. You need to use `parse` instead:

```
expr = parse(text = form)
```

Comment: @Rbud --> if it worked, best practice = accept Konrad's answer. :)

Comment: I couldn't do within 10 minutes of posting my question :). So did it now